# SharePoint 2013 Promoted Results - Abbreviation Definition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, promoted-links

In my organization, we've got a lot of abbreviations. I'd like to create a promoted result so that when someone searches for "CSIS", the first result is "CSIS: Canadian Security Intelligence Service".

Has anyone done this before or seen this somewhere? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE - I've tried adding a term store named "Glossary".  Inside here, I've added a couple terms.  I'm unable to get Search to return my term and the definition.  Maybe this needs to be a list somewhere?

Comment: Can you give us a little more info? There are a couple approaches like promoted results and result blocks. The question is how do you want it to be presented? Benny's suggestion will equate the abbreviation and extend the query to the expanded term, but not show a promoted result. Are you keeping the abbreviations in a list?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be a single promoted result, showing the definition of the term right at the top.  There are a lot of configuration options though and I haven't been able to test out the various combinations.

Comment: OK, a couple ideas below.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a thesaurus .csv file and import it to SharePoint. The file should look like this (which will map search queries expressions both ways):

```
Key,Synonym,Language
CSIS,Canadian Security Intelligence Service
Canadian Security Intelligence Service,CSIS
```

Then run these commands in PowerShell

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication 
Import-SPEnterpriseSearchThesaurus -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename <Path>
```

Reference: [Create and deploy a thesaurus in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219579.aspx)

Comment: I tried the thesaurus but the results weren't what I was looking for.  This allows a user to retrieve the same results while searching for CSIS and Canadian Security Intelligence Service.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to implement this.

1. **Promoted Result** - You could create a Promoted Result for each, though I think if you had more that a few this would be a huge pain to maintain.
2. **Acronym List** - You could add all of your acronyms to a list with an "expansion" and "description" field. Then then create a Result Block when a search query ends in a hit. Create a Display Template for this list item and you are done. I tested this out based on your idea and it works very well. (I'll post a blog article about this approach if I can get the time over the holidays.)
3. **Managed Metadata** - You can create a Query Rule that hits on an MMS term set. Though this sounds easy to maintain I found it hard to render the results in a meaningful way, visually. This may be an approach with merit, though I could not figure it out as fast as the Acronym List.

I hope this helps steer you to a few options.

Comment: Yeah, the Promoted Result is what I had in mind.  I'll have to try out that Acronym List - sounds promising!

Comment: Someone also suggested having a web part display the Glossary search so it could float to the right without disturbing search results.

Comment: Sure, same approach, just hard code the query.